# Do they dream they're superheroes, or do they really become superheroes?

Tags: pj-masks

This might be for someone that has read the original French books [Les Pyjamasques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Pyjamasques). I obviously am not watching kids TV. Honest.

I'm wonder if their nighttime superhero world has any better explanation. In the daytime they are definitely just regular kids, so do they dream they're superheroes or is the premise that they really do become superheroes? Or is it just left to your imagination?

Comment: I would think it's just purely fictional (much like paw patrol and puppy dog pals), because all of their antagonists would have to be someone else, maybe in the class--but we never know.

Comment: @Mike except that PAW Patrol takes place in Canada and is completely normal.

Comment: I have only half-watched this while doing other things but I believe I have noticed the Pyjama Masks talking about their fears amongst themselves during the day. I will pay closer attention and try to get an answer.